# Fonts broken in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

in most browsers the site I am creating is fine. But in Google Chrome the font I'm using has lots of cracks in it and doesn't render properly at all.

Chrome:

[image: Picture]

FireFox:

[image]

I've tried various fixes for it but am still unable to get it to how the site is on firefox. Here is my CSS for the font face:

```
@font-face {
  font-feature-settings:'liga=0';
  font-feature-settings:'liga' 0;
  -moz-font-feature-settings:'liga=0';
  -moz-font-feature-settings:'liga' 0;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings:'liga=0';
  -webkit-font-feature-settings:'liga' 0;
  font-family:'ChampagneLimousines';
  src: url('/Resources/CLB.eot'); /* IE9 */
  src:url('/Resources/CLB.svg') format('svg'),url('/Resources/CLB.woff') format('woff'),url('/Resources/CLB.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight:700;
  font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: The question does not disclose any information about the font. The odds are that the problem relates just to font rendering differences across browsers (there are several old questions about that). The practical solution is probably to stop trying to use too thin fonts.

Comment: Also: when you're having issues with font rendering, please add the operating system you are on (Win, Mac, Linux,...). Font rendering does not only depend on the browser but also on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

- Get the official web font files for your font if possible
- Otherwise use a tool like the font squirrel generator
- Use the [bulletproof font face syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax)
- Use the [Chrome SVG font trick](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/smoother-rendering-in-chrome-update) for smoother rendering in Chrome
- Chrome renders better at certain font sizes than others. Try setting e.g. `font-size: 16px` then incrementing / decrementing 1px at a time to find a compromise
- It could just be that your web font is badly hinted, so find an alternate one

Note that Chrome, Firefox and IE all use different font rendering engines, so they'll always look a bit different

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:
**Control panel-> Fonts -> Adjust clear type.**
I found this solution and it worked for me.